# Cursor and booting problems on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, cursor

I have an ASUS ZenBook Flip UX360CA notebook running a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I'm a noob at Ubuntu, but I have been using it for a while now, maybe 6 months now. I haven't had any major problems until today when my mouse cursor stopped working. It would sometimes disappear form the screen and sometimes freeze up, but regardless it was unresponsive when I tried to use the touchpad.

I saw a suggestion to install gdm and I rebooted with gdm, but Ubuntu didn't even start up with gdm. So now I'm posting this from my Windows part of my dual install, and thank God I have touchscreen on my laptop. It really sucks though since I had all of my projects and such on Ubuntu.

Here's the thing though, my cursor doesn't even work on Windows now either. It turns out the touchpad doesn't work since the cursor reappears when I connect a mouse. However I can't seem to reboot into Ubuntu anymore after I changed lightdm into gdm. All I'm getting is a purple/black screen on startup.

Comment: Did you try using another mouse, specially if this a wired mouse? Usually, their wire gets damaged near ends.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me, since it happens on both OSes.  When the cursor disappears, the "mouse" (or touchpad) isn't recognized; if it freezes, it's not working.  Like @user.dz says, try using another mouse.

Comment: Yeah, turns out the touchpad doesn't work since the cursor reappears when I connect a mouse. However, I can't seem to reboot into ubuntu anymore after I changed lightdm into gdm. All I'm getting is a purple/black screen on startup...

Answer (score 0):

lightdm is a more lightweight login display manager the GDM, which is why it's called lightdm. GDM being heavier than lightdm sometimes has problems booting on some systems. When your laptop stops at the purple/black screen do as follows:

1. Open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Now you are logged in to a text-only console, and you can run terminal commands from the console. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
   ```

   This will open up a new screen allowing you to select either gdm3 or lightdm as the default login display manager. Use the up/down arrow keyboard keys to select lightdm and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the default login display manager selection screen will go back to the default console screen.
5. Reboot the computer and it will start normally.

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
6. When you have rebooted back to your Ubuntu 16.04 desktop check to see if all the usual panel icons are in their proper place in the upper right corner of the desktop. Sometimes the first time you reboot after switching the default login display manager some panel icons may be missing, but you can bring back the missing panel icons by running these two commands from the terminal:

   ```
   setsid compiz --replace    
   setsid unity
   ```